# Find PDF(X,Y) from PDF(X) and PDF(Y)

Tags: machine-learning, density-function, kernel-smoothing

given that X and Y are not mutually exclusive, is there anyway to calculate PDF(X,Y) from PDF(X) and PDF(Y)? 
Following are a few plots made from the dataset.
[image]

In above image i have to find how PDF(11,56) is related to PDF(11), PDF(56). And in this case X and Y are not independent, but this might not always be true.
[image]
[image]

the dataset looks like this:

```
    diagnosis_ids   visit_days
0   (602,)      2
4   (3, 131)    2
5   (13,)       1
6   (442,)      3
7   (761,)      8
9   (28,)       2
10  (17,)       1
11  (13,)       1
12  (44,)       5
13  (9,)        2
14  (146,)      16
16  (9,)        2
17  (146, 336)  7
19  (88,)       5
20  (9,)        1

shape==> 75000 x 2
number of unique diagnosis_ids == 2000
visit_days == length of hospital stay in days.
max(len(diagnosis_ids)) = 6 (this is maximum len available in dataset, new entries can be longer than 6)
```

the final goal is to predict visit_days for a given combination of diagnosis_ids.

Comment: What do you mean by mutually exclusive? By PDF you mean probability densities?

Comment: yes PDF's are probability density functions and by mutually exclusive i mean any diagnosis_id can be combined with any other diagnosis_id, means a patient can have more than one diagnoses.

Comment: This may help: http://www.math.chalmers.se/~rootzen/highdimensional/SSP4SE-appA.pdf if you are assuming normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your question is about finding P(X, Y) in general or do you mean it for a concrete example.

In general your question translates into ill-posed problem: there can be many such distributions. Read on [joint distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution) on wikipedia.

In your example on the other hand your data defines concrete distribution P(X,Y), so it's possible to calculate it using 2-d histograms, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332750/python-joint-distribution-of-n-variables) (Python)

Comment: please explain how to calculate it using 2d histograms. The question is about finding P(X1, X2, ..Xn) from the dataset. While many diagnosis_combinations are already present in dataset many new can be created. The final goal is to spit out a number for visit_days given a combination of diagnosis_ids.